# Convert a pandas dataframe column of type object to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that holds the image id, image class and image data:

```
img_train.head(5)

   ID  index  class                                               data
0  10472  10472      0  [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
1   7655   7655      0  [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
2   6197   6197      0  [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
3   9741   9741      0  [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
4   9169   9169      0  [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
```

I am trying to convert each of these columns to a numpy array:

```
train_img_array = np.array([])
train_id_array = np.array([])
train_lab_array = np.array([])
count = 0
for index, row in img_train.iterrows():
    imgid = row['ID']
    imgclass = row['class']
    imgdata = row['data']
    #print(imgdata)
    train_img_array = np.append(train_img_array, imgdata )
    train_lab_array = np.append(train_lab_array, imgclass )
    train_id_array = np.append(train_id_array, imgid )
```

However, the the column that holds the image data and is of the type 'object' is not getting translated into corresponding row in the numpy array. For instance, this is the shape of each numpy array after processing 58 rows from the original dataframe:

```
train_img_array.shape
train_lab_array.shape
train_id_array.shape
(93615200,)
(58,)
(58,)
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: It returns something like this:
array([ array([[[255, 255, 255,   0],
        [255, 255, 255,   0],
        [255, 255, 255,   0],
        ..., 
        [255, 255, 255,   0],
        [255, 255, 255,   0],
        [255, 255, 255,   0]],

Comment: Could you please give more information? Especially `row['ID'].values.dtype`, `row['class'].values.dtype` and `row['data'].values.dtype` would be helpful.

Comment: @Scotty1- Here's the dtypes:
ID        int64 ***
class     int64 ***
data     object ***
dtype: object

Comment: Thanks, but you should improve the code formatting so that it is human-readable. And more information on shapes etc. will also help.

Comment: `img_train.values` should give you a numpy array, doesn't it?

Comment: @Sören: Yes it does

Comment: @Scotty1- : i have added the shape related details to the post already

Comment: Nope, not the relevant ones. `imgdata.shape`?

Comment: img_train['data'].shape gives this : (8020,)

Comment: This can't be ok, since in your question you say that the resulting shape is `(93615200,)` There is no way that this is multiplicative of 58 and or 8020. There must be some irregular shapes in you data.

Comment: @Scotty1- : That's the problem. The img_train is a pandas dataframe which holds the data properly. I am trying to convert the 'data' column of the pandas dataframe to a numpy array. That's when i run in to the said problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question. It's rather very straight forward and i just did not see it to begin with. This is how i get the object data as well in to numpy array (.values :) )

```
train_img_array = np.array([])
train_id_array = np.array([])
train_lab_array = np.array([])
train_id_array = img_train['ID'].values
train_lab_array = img_train['class'].values
train_img_array =img_train['data'].values
#train_img_array = np.row_stack(img_train['data'])
```

Comment: you dont need to declare the arrays upfront unless you want to specify the size of the arrays.